sway: broadcast keystrokes to multiple containers/views/windows
Same problem like here, but for sway containers, not just a terminal emulator.
For example, having three instances of a browser in a workspace and sending input through keystrokes to all of them simultaneously. Maybe something like an option to focus on multiple containers at the same time?
Is there any way to achieve this?
Many thanks in advance :)
